# Lifespan lines in TeX

Tags: macros, tex-core

I'm writing a document (written in plainTeX) about the lives of important mathematicians and physicists in human history.

Now I have a problem I'd like to tackle. I need to be able to *visualize* their lifespans (so that reader can see who was whose contemporary/coeval). Unfortunatelly, I'm not that skilled in making TeX's macros. Can anyone give me a hint how to do it?

Specifically, I imagine it would work this way:

```
\person{name}{surname}{year_of_birth}{year_of_death}
\person{name}{surname}{year_of_birth}{year_of_death}
...
\renderpeople
```

which would produce (for instance, with instances of Bach & Mozart)

```
Bach J.S.              |----------------|
Mozart A.                      |-----------------|
...
          |----------|-----------|----------|-----------|---------|
       1750        1800        1850       1900        1950      2000
```

Mainly, how would one implement rescaling of lines, so they would fit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What package supports this kind of timeline?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50114/what-package-supports-this-kind-of-timeline)

Comment: @Jake The question is is about plain, whereas the linked one is about 'packages', and so almost certainly LaTeX.

Comment: @JosephWright: The solution of Herbert and David a nearly plain ;-)

Comment: @JosephWright: Oops, sorry, missed the PlainTeX info completely.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A quick hack in plain TeX using vanilla TeX. First the person data are collected
and some values are calculated (minimal year, maximal year, width of names), then
the collected person data are set and finally the whole time line is printed.

```
\newdimen\NameWidth
\NameWidth=0pt
\newcount\MinYear
\MinYear=100000
\newcount\MaxYear
\MaxYear=-100000
\newtoks\PersonData
\PersonData={}
\newdimen\ScaleWidth
\newdimen\ScaleUnit
\newcount\TempCount
\newdimen\TickMarkWidth
\TickMarkWidth=.4pt
\newdimen\TickMarkHeight
\TickMarkHeight=8pt
\newdimen\LineWidth
\LineWidth=.4pt
\newdimen\LastYearCorr

\def\person#1#2#3#4{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\makeperson{#1}{#2}\personsep}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\NameWidth
    \NameWidth=\wd0 %
  \fi
  \ifnum#3<\MinYear
    \MinYear=#3\relax
  \fi
  \ifnum#4>\MaxYear
    \MaxYear=#4\relax
  \fi
  \ifnum#3>#4\relax
    \errmessage{#2 #1 has negative live span, born in #3 and died in #4}%
  \fi
  \PersonData=\expandafter{\the\PersonData
    \DoPerson{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  }%
}
\def\makeperson#1#2{#1, #2}%
\def\personsep{ }
\def\renderpeople{%
  \par
  \divide\MinYear by 50\relax
  \multiply\MinYear by 50\relax
  \advance\MaxYear by 49\relax 
  \divide\MaxYear by 50\relax  
  \multiply\MaxYear by 50\relax
  \ScaleWidth=\hsize
  \advance\ScaleWidth by -\NameWidth
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\textstyle\the\MaxYear$}%
  \LastYearCorr=.5\wd0 %
  \advance\ScaleWidth by -\LastYearCorr
  \ScaleUnit=\ScaleWidth
  \TempCount=\MaxYear   
  \advance\TempCount by -\MinYear
  \divide\ScaleUnit by \TempCount
  \ScaleWidth=\ScaleUnit
  \multiply\ScaleWidth by \TempCount
  \noindent
  \the\PersonData
  \ScaleLine
  \par
}
\def\DoPerson#1#2#3#4{%
  \hbox to \hsize{%
    \hbox to \NameWidth{%
      \makeperson{#1}{#2}%
      \hfill
      \personsep
    }%
    \hfill
    \hbox to \ScaleWidth{%
      \kern#3\ScaleUnit   
      \kern-\MinYear\ScaleUnit
      \SetTickMark
      \TempCount=#4\relax
      \advance\TempCount by -#3\relax
      \SetLine\TempCount
      \SetTickMark
      \hfill
    }%
    \kern\LastYearCorr
  }%
  \hskip0pt\relax
}
\def\ScaleLine{%
  \hbox to \hsize{%
    \hbox to \NameWidth{\hfill}%
    \hfill
    \hbox to \ScaleWidth{%
      \TempCount=\MinYear 
      \SetTickYearMark    
      \loop
      \ifnum\TempCount<\MaxYear
        \SetLine{50}%
        \advance\TempCount by 50 %
        \SetTickYearMark
      \repeat
    }%
    \kern\LastYearCorr
  }%
  \hskip0pt\relax
}
\def\SetTickYearMark{%
  \hbox to 0pt{%
    \hss
    $\mathsurround=0pt\relax
      \mathop{\vcenter{%
        \hrule width \TickMarkWidth
               height .5\TickMarkHeight
               depth .5\TickMarkHeight 
      }}\limits_{\textstyle\the\TempCount}%
    $%
    \hss
  }%
}   
\def\SetTickMark{%
  \hbox to 0pt{%  
    \hss
    $\mathsurround=0pt\vcenter{%
      \hrule width \TickMarkWidth
             height .5\TickMarkHeight
             depth .5\TickMarkHeight 
    }$%
    \hss
  }%
}   
\def\SetLine#1{%
  $\mathsurround=0pt\vcenter{%
    \hrule width#1\ScaleUnit  
           height.5\LineWidth 
           depth.5\LineWidth  
  }$%
}

\person{Pachelbel}{J.}{1653}{1706}
\person{Bach}{J. S.}{1685}{1750}  
\person{Mozart}{W. A.}{1756}{1791}
\person{Euler}{L.}{1707}{1783}

\renderpeople
\bye
```

> [image: Timelines via plain and vanilla TeX]

Remarks:

- I would prefer e-TeX's `\dimexpr` and `\numexpr` if they are available; they
  are more comfortable. However divisions are different, because the
  `\...expr` are rounding the result.
- The powerful `pgf/TikZ` is available in plain TeX, too.

Answer (score 11):

here is a similiar TeX solution:

```
\input pst-grad
\input pstricks-add
\newbox\TBox
\psset{gradbegin=white,gradend=lightgray}
\catcode`\@11\relax

\def\BoxText{\@ifnextchar[\BoxText@i{\BoxText@i[3cm]}}
\def\BoxText@i[#1]#2#3#4{%
  \emergencystretch=3em
  \setbox\TBox\vbox{\hsize #1 #4\par}
  \rput[t](#2){\psframebox[fillstyle=gradient]{\leavevmode\copy\TBox\relax}}%
  \pnode(#2|0,0){A}\pnode(#2){B}
  \ncline{->}{A}{B}%
  \uput*{0.5cm}[-90](A){#3}%
}
\catcode`\@12\relax

\pspicture(0,0.25)(2.5,-10)
\psset{xunit=5}
\psaxes[yAxis=false,Ox=1518]{|->}(0,0)(2.5,-10)% 
\BoxText[4cm]{1.1123,-5.5}{10.2.}{%
Hier muss jetzt irgendetwas hinkommen, was, weiss ich auch nicht genau}
\BoxText{.767,-2}{15.10.}{%
Hier muss jetzt irgendetwas hinkommen, was, weiss ich auch nicht genau}
\endpspicture


\pspicture(0,0.25)(2.5,-10)
\psset{xunit=5cm}
\psaxes[yAxis=false,Ox=1518]{|->}(0,0)(2.5,-10)%
\BoxText{.787,-5}{17.10.}{%
Hier muss jetzt irgendetwas hinkommen, was, weiss ich auch nicht genau}
\pnode(A){A0}
\BoxText{.767,-2}{15.10.}{%
Hier muss jetzt irgendetwas hinkommen, was, weiss ich auch nicht genau}
\uput*{1.2cm}[-90](A0){17.10.}%
\endpspicture

\bye
```

[image]