# Timeline with automatized hours and minutes

Tags: tikz-pgf, automation

Some time ago I've asked [a question about Timelines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50114/4778), many solutions were given, but in the end I decided to go with TikZ and also [presented my solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55042/4778). But I couldn't have done it without [Torbjørn T.'s comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50114/what-package-supports-this-kind-of-timeline/55042#comment117160_55042), where he suggested to make the creation of dates automatic, and this helped since I didn't need to type all of that myself and above all, it saved space in my Tex document. The solution was<sup>1</sup>:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,snakes}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

       %draw horizontal line   
       \draw[|->, -latex] (0,0) -- (17,0);
       \draw[-, dashed] (-1,0) -- (0,0);

       %draw years

       \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \year using int(1790+\x*10)] in {0,1,...,17}{ 

            \draw (\x,0) node[below=7pt,anchor=east,xshift=0,rotate=45] {$\year$}; 
            }

       \draw[] (0,-0.1) -- (0,0.1);
       \draw[] (1,-0.1) -- (1,0.1);
       \draw[] (2,-0.1) -- (2,0.1);
       \draw[] (3,-0.1) -- (3,0.1);
       \draw[] (4,-0.1) -- (4,0.1);
       \draw[] (5,-0.1) -- (5,0.1);
       \draw[] (6,-0.1) -- (6,0.1);
       \draw[] (7,-0.1) -- (7,0.1);
       \draw[] (8,-0.1) -- (8,0.1);
       \draw[] (9,-0.1) -- (9,0.1);
       \draw[] (10,-0.1) -- (10,0.1);
       \draw[] (11,-0.1) -- (11,0.1);
       \draw[] (12,-0.1) -- (12,0.1);
       \draw[] (13,-0.1) -- (13,0.1);
       \draw[] (14,-0.1) -- (14,0.1);
       \draw[] (15,-0.1) -- (15,0.1);
       \draw[] (16,-0.1) -- (16,0.1);

   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result was:

[image: screenshot]

... And it continues (too long to fit here). Now I want to recreate this but with hours and minutes, so that at the bottom of the line I can see `00:00` then `01:00` and so on.

This could be indefinite, as I have the intention of making a long horizontal document (not going to be printed, only digital use so no problem).

I have tried tweaking that code and searching this site but to no avail. How should I go about it? Is the code good for years but not for time as I want it? I really don't know where to start.

---

<sup>1: This is actually a minimal working example. I'm referring to the lines reported in the comment.</sup>

Comment: Can you post what you tried so as to determine what went wrong with using `HH:MM` instead of years?  Replacing the `\foreach` with `\foreach \x  in {0,...,17}{ 
            \draw (\x,0) node[below=7pt,anchor=east,xshift=0,rotate=45] {$\x\colon 00$}; 
            }` seems to work just fine.  You can also eliminate all the manual `draw` commands by using `\draw[] (\x,-0.1) -- (\x,0.1);` within the `\foreach` loop.

Comment: @PeterGrill I didn't write `{$\x\colon 00$};`, just touching the `using int(1790+\x*10)]` part which gave errors. I'm not that expert. :D Now that you mention it, I did the automatized thing for the lines somewhere else, this one was a pretty old code. But thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Follow-up Question: [Have \foreach restart or loop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75922/have-foreach-restart-or-loop).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By a slight change to the `\foreach` loop you get what I think is the desired result:

[image]

### Notes:

You can greatly simplify your code:

- I commented out the package not needed for this MWE.
- By setting `\MaxNumber`you can easily change one parameter and increase the width of the picture (page dimensions need to be adjust).
- The individual `\draw` commands could be in the `\foreach` loop.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, landscape]{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,snakes}

\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{17}%
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       %draw horizontal line   
       \draw[|->, -latex] (0,0) -- (\MaxNumber,0);
       \draw[-, dashed] (-1,0) -- (0,0);

       %draw hours
       \foreach \x  in {0,...,\MaxNumber} {% 
            \draw (\x,0) node[below=7pt,anchor=east,xshift=0,rotate=45] {\x:00}; 
            \draw[] (\x,-0.1) -- (\x,0.1);
            }
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Peter, I've deleted my previous comments (just letting you know so you could delete yours). But I have another side question. I kind of forgot to mention this. If I raise the `\MaxNumber`, hours continue indefinitely. But I want them to act like... hours. So when it reaches "23:00", I'd like it to restart at "00:00" again and not continue to 24, 25, 26... I'd appreciate even an hint. I've tried looking around but I have no idea. :| Thanks in advance.

Comment: As that is also unrelated to drawing things that would also be better asked as a separate question. That way others who have a similar question are more likely to find it rather than have it buried in this question. There are probably many ways to do that using mod arithmetic. I would probably use something like `\pgfmathmod`

Comment: Uhm ok I'll ask a question later. :)

Comment: @Alenanno: I have corrected the way the `HH:MM` were being typeset by not placing the text in math mode, and removed the use of `\colon`.  Please see updated answer.