# How to create a table like I do in Word

Tags: tables

I searched for examples with Google about how to create a table like this with LaTeX but nothing can help me, so I just make the question here.

[image]

Comment: What do those black arrows mean?

Comment: it seems to be a Gannt chart

Comment: Black arrows mean that work begin in week 1 to week 3 for exemple ic an change it with something else

Comment: Maybe using `\usepackage{pgfgantt}` ?

Comment: I guess he is looking for something like [`calc2latex`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/calc2latex/), which allows you to save your OpenOffice.org spreadsheets as LaTeX tables.

Comment: @Henri Menke i work on windows 7

Comment: @Zero-dev Then you might want to take a look at [`Ex­cel-to-LaTeX`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex). This is an addons for Excel which allows you to export your spreadsheets as LaTeX tables, but don't expect it to do any fancy styling for you. It is just a data exporter.

Comment: Very cool but dont do the work as well as i want, and using **\usepackage{pgfgantt}** it's good to me Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you are looking for a Gantt diagram.  The package `pgfgantt` takes care of this.  Simply add to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
```

The package documentation (with examples) is available [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf)

---

Related posts that you might find useful:

[What package supports this kind of timeline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50114/what-package-supports-this-kind-of-timeline/50118#50118)

http://www.martin-kumm.de/tex_gantt_package.php

Comment: thats a useful example thanks a lot i will try and replay again

Comment: You're welcome, but please keep in mind that instead of posting a “Thank you” as an additional answer, you should give feedback by replying “Yes” to the question “Was this post useful to you?”. You’ll find this question under every post. Once you’ve gathered 15 reputation points on this site, you’ll be able to [upvote answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: i do flow the tuto step by step and i fnally get wat i lookin for, thanks  that was useful and helpful 10+