# Timeline for overlapping (multi-year) events

Tags: beamer

I'd like to generate a timeline similar to the one shown below:

[image: http://www.projects.science.uu.nl/tm5/TM5_PW/TM5_presentations_May2011/basu.pdf]

[original at: http://www.projects.science.uu.nl/tm5/TM5_PW/TM5_presentations_May2011/basu.pdf]

How can I go about doing that? thanks!

Cheers,
M.

Comment: Perhaps `pgfgantt` package could be useful. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50114/what-package-supports-this-kind-of-timeline)