# Making simple figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm a new user of LaTeX and hope some of you can help me with this.

How can I, in a simple way, make a figure similar to this?

[image: figure]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: There are some dedicated packages for such things, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217834/how-to-create-a-timeline-with-latex for a few examples.

Comment: or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50118/36296

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\itshape]
\foreach \i [count=\xi] in {-2,-1.5,...,2}
    \node (t\xi) at (2*\i,0) {\i};
\node[left = of t1, anchor=center] (time) {Time};
\node[right = of t9, anchor=center] (dots) {\dots};
\draw (time.south west) -- (dots.east|-time.south);

\foreach \i [count=\xi from 0, count=\ni from 5] in {1,2,3,4}{
    \draw[Circle-Circle] ([yshift=-1cm-1.2cm*\xi]t\i.center)--node[above]{formation} ([yshift=-1cm-1.2cm*\xi]t\ni.center);
    \draw[Circle-Circle] ([yshift=-1.5cm-1.2cm*\xi]t\ni.center)--node[above]{trading} ++(0:1);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]